# SWC Mesher Add-on not showing up in Add-ons

Tags: python, mesh, add-on, installation

I am desperately trying to install one add-on in Blender, however, it will just not show up in the list of Add-ons. Tee Add-on can be obtained here: https://github.com/mcellteam/swc_mesher/tree/master/files/description
So far, I tested Blender versions 2.93, 2.8, 2.78a and 2.79. I installed the app (zip file) using the "install an add-on" button in preferences/add-on or manually (by putting the unpacked folder in the scripts/addons folder (both in the "program files/Blender...." and users/roaming/App Data/Blender...). Can anyone get this add-on to work?

Thanks in advance for any help

Sander

Comment: What error messages are you getting from the attempt?

Comment: There is no error at all. Installing it via the "addons tap" works properly (no error message), however, it is just not in the list so that I can make my little checkbox...